# ActiveMQ on one server not listening on port 61616 while it listens on other server

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have activemq installed on two RHEL servers. On first server, it works fine, and when I test the following command:

```
[tan@myservername1 apache-activemq-5.15.8]$  netstat -natp | grep 61616
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61616           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41290         127.0.0.1:61616         ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:61616         127.0.0.1:41290         ESTABLISHED -
```

When I run the similar command on second server, it doesn't shows above stats as shown below:

```
[activemq@myservername apache-activemq-5.15.11]$ netstat -a |grep 61616
[activemq@myservername apache-activemq-5.15.11]$
```

What could be the reason? I tested the second server `myservername` to see whether it's running or not I it looks like its running as shown in the commands below:

```
[activemq@myservername apache-activemq-5.15.11]$ bin/activemq start
INFO: Loading '/web/servers/apache-activemq-5.15.11//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/web/servers/apache-activemq-5.15.11//data/activemq.pid' (pid '6996')
```

Then I double checked like the following:

```
[activemq@myservername apache-activemq-5.15.11]$ bin/activemq start
INFO: Loading '/web/servers/apache-activemq-5.15.11//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/bin/java'
INFO: Process with pid '6996' is already running
```

How can I troubleshoot this second server so that it displays same results like the first one? My spring boot application won't be able to connect until it establishes a connection with port 61616.